# How can I prove $\int f d\mu$ exists if $f$ s measurable and $\int |f|d\mu<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> If I take $f:(\Omega, F)\rightarrow (\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$ to be a measurable function such that $\int |f| d\mu <\infty$.
> Is it then true that $\int f d\mu$ exists?

I would say yes, and my proof would be the following.

Remark that $f=f^+-f^-$, and we know that $f$ is measurable iff $f^+,f^-$ are measurable. So $\int f d\mu=\int f^+ d\mu-\int f^- d\mu<2\int |f| d\mu<\infty$. So I would conclude that $\int fd\mu$ exists. Does this work?

Comment: Yes, looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof does not work, as $f$ can have any sign, and so a bound $\int_\Omega f~\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$ does not actually prove that the integral exists. What you could do, however, is use that

$$0\leq f^+\leq\lvert f\rvert,$$

and

$$0\leq f^-\leq\lvert f\rvert,$$

from which you then have that

$$\int_\Omega f^+~\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int_\Omega \lvert f\rvert~\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$$

and

$$\int_\Omega f^-~\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int_\Omega \lvert f\rvert~\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty,$$

which shows that both of those integrals exist and are finite, since we are dealing with non-negative integrands. It then follows from the definition of $\int_\Omega f~\mathrm{d}\mu$, as both of the above integrals are finite, that the integral exists.

Comment: But I also used exactly that $\int f^\pm d\mu \leq \int |f|d\mu<\infty$? so where is my error?

Comment: Your error is that you try to draw the conclusion from getting $\int f~\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$, which is simply not a correct step

Comment: but in my proof it is true that $\int fd\mu <\infty$? but the only problem is that $\int fd\mu<\infty$ does mean that $\int f d\mu$ exists?

Comment: @cristallo The problem with your proof is that while you are doing the correct thing, you are notating it the wrong way :). A measurable function is integrable iff the integral of the positive part and the negative part are not both $\infty$ (so nothing like $\infty - \infty$ happens). You do argue that $\int f^+ - \int f^-$ is finite. But this is not what you want to prove. What you want to prove is that $\int f^+ - \int f^-$ actually makes sense. And this follows from the same observation, that is, $\int f^+, \int f^-$ are both bounded by $\int|f|<\infty$.

Comment: @cristallo But in fact you do not need that both parts are finite. The integral still exists if it is infinite.

Comment: ah okey so what I did  (show that $\int f d\mu<\infty$) is not wrong but the problem is that I can't deduce from this that it actually makes sense. But what exactly does it mean that $\int f^+ - \int f^-$ makes sense, so it does not mean that it is not $\infty$? @Lazy

Comment: The way you've written it currently basically boils down to saying "if the integral exists, then it does not equal $\infty$"

Comment: @Lorago ah so the integral $\int f d\mu$ can be infinite to exists but what's important is that I don't get $\infty-\infty$ in the positive and negative part? That's why I need to show that positive and negative parts are finite

Comment: @cristallo Yes, exactly!

Comment: @cristallo Yep, that's right!

Comment: perfect thanks!

Comment: but if positive and negative part can not be infinite to be integrable, then how can the integral be infinite? @Lazy

Comment: @cristallo The situation $\infty-\infty$ arises only if both integrals are infinite. It thus suffices that one of both integrals is finite. Thus the other one can be infinite, leading to either $\infty-c = \infty$ or $c-\infty = -\infty$.

Comment: @cristallo Here's a bit of a question of convention, but as far as I know the general definition is that $f$ is integrable if both $\int f^+~\mathrm{d}\mu$ and $\int f^-~\mathrm{d}\mu$ are finite, and so in that case $\int f~\mathrm{d}\mu$ exists and is finite. However saying that $\int f~\mathrm{d}\mu$ exists is slightly weaker as it only requires that \textbf{at least one of} $\int f^+~\mathrm{d}\mu$ and $\int f^-~\mathrm{d}\mu$ is finite, as that's all that's required for $\int f~\mathrm{d}\mu$ to be well defined

Comment: @Lorago There’s multiple ways of doing it. Some people use integrable as *exists + is finite*. I’ve learned integrable as *exists* and summable as *is finite*. But I’ve also seen cases where they used summable for *exists* and integrable for *is finite*.

Comment: @Lazy indeed I know there are several conventions, hence why I started by saying that it's a bit of a questions of convention

Comment: @Lorago I was in no way trying to undermine your credibility, just expanding on your question of convention :)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a measurable function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if $\int f^+<\infty$ and $\int f^-<\infty$. In this case
$$ \int f := \int f^+ - \int f^-. $$
The nonnegative measurable functions $f^+,f^-$ are pointwise limits of simple functions and their integrals are obtained via monotone convergence.

Comment: so my proof is not correct?

Comment: @cristallo I would say your attempt is circular. You assume that $\int f$ exists and is equal to some quantity and then proceed to prove...it exists?

Comment: where do I assume $\int f$ exists?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.